# why this program still output "not null"?

Tags: c#, .net

why this program still output "not null" even if everything is empty?! What do i have to change to finally make it null?

"Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly." Sorry for that...

```
public interface IDrawable 
{
    void Draw();
}

public interface IAdvancedDraw : IDrawable
{
    void DrawInBoundingBox();
    void DrawUpsideDown();
}

public class BitmapImage : IAdvancedDraw
{
    public void Draw() { }
    public void DrawInBoundingBox() { }
    public void DrawUpsideDown() { }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {

        BitmapImage myBitmap = new BitmapImage();

        if ((IAdvancedDraw)myBitmap != null){
            Console.WriteLine("not null"); 
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are confusing empty methods with a null object. `BitmapImage myBitmap;` will give you null but `BitmapImage myBitmap = new BitmapImage();` will create an instance of the class which will not be equal to null

Comment: Why do you think that the `(IAdvancedDraw)myBitmap` must be `NULL`?

Comment: Maybe you actually want to learn the [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=vs.110).aspx) operator and inheritance. But then you need to try-cast to a wrong type like string to get a `null`. Since `BitmapImage` inherits from `IAdvancedDraw` the cast succeeds.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I was just playing around with this program that i found in my book about c# to have a better comprehension

Comment: When using `(IAdvancedDraw)myBitmap` you'll get an `InvalidCastException` instead of a null object if `myBitmap` is not a `IAdvancedDraw`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is initialized it is not null.

```
BitmapImage myBitmap = new BitmapImage();
```

[new Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You're always getting `"not null'` because there's always *something* in `myBitmap` - after all, you just created a `new BitmapImage()` and put it there!